# Defining variable in projectile motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, drag, textbook-erratum

I'm trying to understand drag on projectile motion but I don't know what this variable $b$ in Eq.1 below on p. 24 in this document is.

> We define the drag force to be $\mathbf{F}_D$ and the gravitational force is $\mathbf{F_g}$. We have
>   $$m\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{F_g}+\mathbf{F_D}=mg\mathbf{\hat y}-b(\mathbf{\hat x}+\mathbf{\hat y}),\tag{1}$$
>   and letting $k=b/m$, we can separate the above equation into $x-$ and $y-$equations. We have
>   $$x''(t)=-kx'(t), \quad y''(t)=-h-ky'(t).\tag{2}$$
>   Next we will solve the above differential equations using the initial conditions:
>   $$x(0)=0; \quad y(0)=h;\tag{3.1}$$
>   $$x'(0)=v\cos\theta; \quad y'(0)=v\sin\theta;\tag{3.2}$$
>   where $v$ is the initial velocity of the projectile. Using separation of variables to solve the $x-$equation, we obtain
>   $$x''(t)=-kx'(t),\tag{4.1}$$
>   $$x'(t)=Ce^{-kt}=v\cos\theta e^{-kt}\tag{4.2}$$
>   $$x(t)=-\frac{v\cos\theta}{k}e^{-kt}+C=\frac{v\cos\theta}{k}\left(1-e^{-kt}\right).\tag{4.3}$$
>   Similarly, for the $y-$equation, we have
>   $$y''(t)=-h-ky'(t)\tag{5.1}$$
>   $$dy'=(-g-ky')dt\tag{5.2}$$
>   $$\frac{dy'}{-g-ky'}=dt\tag{5.3}$$
>   $$\frac{1}{k}\ln(g+ky')=-t+C\tag{5.4}$$

References:

1. Nina Henelsmith, [*Projectile Motion:Finding the Optimal Launch Angle*](https://www.whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/2016/Henelsmith.pdf), Whitman College, 2016; p. 24.

Comment: Hi WaterRocket123, it's against our rules to post images of text you want to quote. Please type it out instead so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Answer (score 2):

$b$ is the [drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) constant for a linear drag force. OP's question might have been spurred by the fact that the first eq. on p. 24 has a typo: The factor $\hat{\bf x}+\hat{\bf y}$ should have been the velocity $\vec{\bf v}=x^{\prime}(t)\hat{\bf x}+y^{\prime}(t)\hat{\bf y}$.